# Redmine IIS7 installation

Tags: iis, redmine

Has anybody here ever managed to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the [Bitnami version?](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The Bitnami installation uses Apache/Mongrel for the web server component and not IIS.

Comment: The link actually has an installer for Windows.

Answer (score 8):

Try this: [Installing Redmine on Windows in production](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/installing-redmine-on-windows-in-production/)